# How do other primates treat their fingernails?

Tags: zoology, anatomy, ethology, mammals, homology

Do all primates have to trim their fingernails in some way, or do some primates' fingernails wear off through natural use?

Also, is constant nail growth common to all primates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both. Many primates bite their nails. Some do not. It's not species specific.

Chimpanzees, for example, usually bite their nails; some prefer to leave them alone. They do grow continuously, and nails not kept trimmed probably break off (looking at the thickness of those nails, I get the impression that this might be rather painful if they break too short.)

The caption for the picture below (taken from a chimpanzee sanctuary) states

> Annie likes to pick Missy’s nose. Missy tolerates it but doesn’t seem to enjoy it. I don’t blame her – Annie doesn’t [bite her nails down](http://www.chimpsanctuarynw.org/blog/tag/grooming/) like the other chimps do.

[image]

They bite their toenails as well.

Comment: The follow-up question then is how do hunter-gatherer societies treat their nails? I'm just curious if continuously growing nails is one of those vestiges of evolution that lost its purpose. It would make more sense if nails grew to a certain length and then stopped (like body hair does). Continuous growth suggests to me that they're like sharks' teeth, they have to be continuously replaced due to wear.

Comment: But none of these require grooming (to the point of necessary discomfort when not treated). You don't really have to do anything about your skin or hair, to the point where if you don't trim them they would cause you significant discomfort on day-to-day activity. Also, body hair certainly doesn't continue to go in length, otherwise most people would look like Chubaka.

Comment: What's the evolutionary reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Why some human beings bite their nails? Because, they are primates - it is inherited way to treat our nails, called **onychophagia**. While normal in some primates (and this is the way they treat their nails), it is considered [abnormal in human](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19479125).

[image]

Comment: Abnormal or just gross?